# MATLAB : Proper estimation of weights and how to calculate MSE for QPSK signal for Constant Modulus Algorithm

Tags: matlab, digital-communications, adaptive-filters, equalization, adaptive-algorithms

I had asked conceptual Question about [Constant Modulus Algorithm](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/23509/constant-modulus-algorithm-and-the-gradient-operation). I am implementing the simple steps of the algorithm, as I do not have the `cma()` built in module.

I am considering a Finite Impulse Response (FIR) system  whose true coefficients are $h = \begin{bmatrix}1 &0.45 &-0.2\end{bmatrix}$. The algorithm is presented briefly :

$u_n$ : Output of the FIR filter that is driven by Input signal, $s$ is a white Gaussian signal that drives an FIR process by the command

```
s=round(rand(1,N))*2-1; 
u = filter(h,1,s);
```

We receive a noisy signal which is the output of the system corrupted by AWGN. Let the noise corrupted signal be

$$x_n = h^T s_n + \eta_n$$
Constructing an equalizer

$$y_n = w^T x_n$$

The cost function to be minimized by gradient descent is

$$J(w) = E\left[\left(\big\lvert y_n\big\rvert^2 -1\right)^2\right]$$

The weight update equation is given by

$$w_{n+1} = w_n - 2\mu e_n  y_n^T x_n$$

where error,

$$e_n = \left(\big\lvert y_n\big\rvert^2 -1\right)$$

Operator $T$ is the transpose and assuming real signals without any imaginary and complex parts.

Below is the code. The algorithm does not give proper result in terms of estimates of the weights.

**Problem 1:** The Graph for the Mean Square Error (in DB) for the estimated weights returned by the algorithm vs. Signal to Noise Ratio is giving an opposite trend i.e. instead of MSE decreasing with increasing SNR, I am getting the opposite when I re-run the program!! Below is the image of what I mean. The first figure is correct, but with the same code, I ran it again and got the second figure. Why is this & how can I prevent it?
[image: Fig1]

[image: Fig2]

I am not sure if this is due to the initialization of the variable $L$, filter order = number of delays = 2. Somethings are not straight for me which are for the FIR filter of the form : $u(t) = e(t) + 0.45e(t-1) - 0.2e(t-2)$, what is the filter order, smoothing length and the number of weights unknown to be estimated?
 Can somebody please help so that it works?

```
   clear all
clc

N = 256;
h = [1    0.45   -0.2];

R2 = 2;

mu =  1.0000e-009;
noisedB  =0;

L=2; % smoothing length L+1
ChL=1;  % length of the channel= ChL+1
EqD=round((L+ChL)/2);  %  channel equalization delay

i=sqrt(-1);

Ch=[1 0.45 -0.2]; %Channel
%Ch=[0.8+i*0.1 .9-i*0.2]; %complex channel
Ch=Ch/norm(Ch);% normalize


skip =1
for l=1:6
i          = 1; 

 TxS=round(rand(1,N))*2-1;  % QPSK symbols are transmitted symbols
%TxS=TxS+sqrt(-1)*(round(rand(1,N))*2-1);
x=filter(Ch,1,TxS); %channel distortion

n=randn(1,N);   % additive white gaussian noise

n=n/norm(n)*10^(-noisedB/20)*norm(x);  % scale noise power
x1=x+n;  % received noisy signal


%estimation using CMA
K=N-L;   %% Discard initial samples for avoiding 0's and negative
X=zeros(L+1,K);  %each vector
for j=1:K
    X(:,j)=x1(j+L:-1:j).';  %y_n = w^T x_n 
end

e=zeros(1,K); 
w=zeros(L+1,1); 
w(EqD)=1;    % initial condition
while i<=K


e(i)=abs(w.'*X(:,i))^2-R2;                  % initial error
   w=w-mu*2*e(i)*X(:,i)*X(:,i)'*w;  % update equalizer co-efficients
    cma_mse_h(l,i)    = sum((w'-h).^2)/3; 
    est_w(i,:) = w;
   w(EqD)= 1;


            i = i+1;


end
noisedB = noisedB + 5;
end 

for ii = 1:6

 Error(ii) = 10*log10(mean(cma_mse_h(ii,:)));
end 

 plot([0:5:25], Error(1:6));
 grid on;
 xlabel ('SNR(dB)')
 ylabel('MSE_h')
```

**Second Problem :** The true FIR channel coefficients are not imaginary and have only real parts. But the estimated weights will have both real & imaginary if I work with real and complex representation. How can I properly calculate the weights & its MSE for this case?

Comment: Some things to try: experiment with your step size, try using normalized LMS instead, and try increasing the number of taps in your equalizer.

Comment: @JasonR: I played around with the step size but not the delay. I am not sure whether for blind CMA we assume the knowledge of the order of the filter. But, yet the same misconvergence issue remains. Another thing is that I am not quite clear what the variable ChL, EqD stand for : I have modified the CMA part of the code found in link http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/39482-blind-channel-equalization/content/lms.m Can you please help me with these initial problems? Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code reveals many misconception about what the CMA is supposed to achieve:

- your step size `mu` is much too small; note, however, that the optimal step size can only be found through experiment.
- the variabe `noisedB` appears to be the desired SNR of the received signal. An SNR of $0\,\text{dB}$ as specified by you is very poor (the noise is as strong as the signal), and in such noisy conditions the CMA cannot perform properly.
- you have a channel with $3$ taps, and your equalizer length is also only $3$ taps; this is much too short to achieve any reasonable equalization.
- you define the MSE as the error between the channel impulse response and the equalizer response. This is wrong, because the equalizer is not supposed to converge to the channel impulse response! The equalizer must *equalize* the channel, i.e. the concatenation of the channel and the equalizer should give a pure delay.

There are a few other small errors in your code, but instead of correcting them all I show you a very simple and short code example. The figure below the code shows the error curve vs symbol index, and the total impulse response of the channel *and* the equalizer. As you can see, it approximates a delta impulse (i.e. no distortion). The SNR is $30\,\text{dB}$ for this example. The error becomes much smaller if there is no noise. For worse SNRs, the algorithm becomes unstable.

```
N = 20000;          % # symbols
h = [1,.45,-.2];    % channel impulse response
h = h/norm(h);
Le = 20;            % equalizer length
mu = .001;          % step size
snr = 30;           % snr in dB

s0 = round( rand(N,1) )*2 - 1;     % BPSK signal
s = filter(h,1,s0);                % filtered signal

% add Gaussian noise at desired snr
n = randn(N,1);
vs = var(s);
vn = vs*10^(-snr/10);
n = sqrt(vn)*n;
r = s + n;          % received signal

e = zeros(N,1);     % error
w = zeros(Le,1);    % equalizer coefficients
w(Le)=1;            % actual filter taps are flipud(w)!

yd = zeros(N,1);

for i = 1:N-Le,
    x = r(i:Le+i-1);
    y = w'*x;
    yd(i)=y;
    e(i) = y^2 - 1;
    w = w - mu * e(i) * y * x;
end

np = 100;           % # sybmols to plot (last np will be plotted); np < N!

subplot(3,1,1), plot(e.*e), title('error')
subplot(3,1,2), stem(conv(flipud(w),h)), title('equalized channel impulse response')
subplot(3,1,3), plot(1:np,s0(N-np+1:N),1:np,yd(N-np+1-Le+1:N-Le+1))
    title('transmitted and equalized signal'), legend('transmitted','equalized'), axis([0,np,-1.5,2])
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your detailed clarification and the code. Could you shed some guidelines on these as these are the objectives that I wanted to achieve hence I had used the MSE in my code ? (1) The thing is I need to compare the performance of CMA in blind system identification and equalization by using the Cramer Rao bound of the coefficients for blind system identification with the MSE of the channel impulse (estimated coefficients).

Comment: Theoretically, MSE of the estimated coefficients $w$ should asymptotically reach the CRLB with increasing SNR. That is the reason I was applying the MSE formula in my code. How can I obtain the MSE of the weights/ coefficients $w$?

Comment: (2) I need to show how close the estimated signal (equalized signal) matches with the estimated signal. Let the clean signal be $u(t) = e(t) + 0.45e(t-1) - 0.2e(t-2)$ and the equalized signal is $y = w.'x$ Then I should do plot((1:N),u,'r'); hold on ; plot((1:N), y)? Lastly, (3) What is the order of the FIR filter $u$? There are 2 delays, so is it a Moving Average(2)? Thanlk you for all your help (previous Questions as well)

Comment: @SKM: (1) This is a totally different question. Your original question is about equalizing a channel, which is different from system identification. So for this point, you should formulate a new question, which clearly states what you need to know. (2) You should compare the equalized signal to the *original* transmitted signal *before* the channel, because the equalizer tries to compensate for the channel. (3) The filter order is indeed 2 (order = length-1).

Comment: Once again, thank you for your effort & time. One last clarification :  Is the equalized signal, $y = w'x$ where $x$ is the received noisy signal and $w$ the estimated weights? For (1) I will post a new Question as to how I should use CMA for System Identification.

Comment: @SKM: That's right, $y$ is the equalized signal which should approximate the originally transmitted signal.

Comment: Hello once gain, sorry for bothering once more. Can you explain please what the second graph implies? The X and Y axis? If the impulse response touches 1 then what does it mean? When I worked with 2000 samples instead of 20k as in your answer t hen the stem plot in second graph did not reach upto 1. Lastly, what will be the command to see how well the equalizer has performed in eliminating noise through a plot of $y$ vs $s$? I did plot([1:50:N], s(1:50:N), 'r')
hold on;
plot([1:50:N], y(1:50:N) ) but it is incorrect because of $y$ ( I am unable to simulate the equalized signal $y$ ) . Thanks.

Comment: @SKM: The second plot is the total impulse response of the channel and the equalizer. If it is a unit impulse then the equalizer compensates perfectly for the channel distortion. As you can see from the first plot (error over time), after 2000 symbols the equalizer has not yet fully converged, so the total impulse response is not yet a unit impulse. As for the plot of the original and equalized symbols, I've added the corresponding code and plot to my answer.

Comment: What should be changed in the accepted solution in order to handle QPSK signals? I mean how to update would change when using complex values. Thanks!

Comment: The following changes are needed:      e(i) = abs(y)^2/2 - 1;
       w = w - mu * e(i) * conj(y) * x;

Comment: @MattL. How come you plot the error squared and not the abs(e) ?

Comment: @BigBrownBear00: It doesn't really matter much as long as you know how the error is defined. The error is real-valued, so square and magnitude squared are the same.

Comment: @MattL. I'm looking to adapt your example to use oversampled data to model a fractionally spaced equalizer. Do you already have an example of that? I can give it a shot and ask a new question if it doesn't work

Comment: I believe the main change for the FSE case is how the $x$ vector is generated

Comment: @MattL. Does the weight calculation have an error? Should it be: w = w + mu * e(i) * x; ?

Comment: @Harris why do you have a /2 factor for QPSK? If the magnitude is 1 for all the QPSK symbols, the squared error would be abs(y)^2 -1 , no?

Comment: If you use +1 and -1 for I and Q then abs(1+1j)^2=2, so you need to normalize by 2